# How do I invalidate the useMutation on success

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

Hi I have below mutation :

```
export const useUserSearch = (data) => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationKey: ["user-search", data],
    mutationFn: fetchUser,
  });
};
```

I am using it in the component :

```
 const {
    mutate,
    data: userInfo,
    isLoading: userInfoLoading,
  } = useUserSearch();
```

Now I have another Mutation which gets called on updation request like below :

```
 const handleCreateRoleConfirm = (data) => {
    createRoleMutate(data, {
      onSuccess: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries("user-search"); // trying to invalidate the above mutaiton
        showAlert({
          message: "The record has been created successfully",
          variant: "success",
        });

        setIsAddDialogOpen(false);
      },
    });
  };
```

Now here in the onsuccess I am trying to invalidate the useUserSearch hooks mutation . But it does not work. Seems like it is not invalidation it an rerigging the api . How do I fix this ?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Mutation keys aren't for validating, they are for **dehydration** and **hydration** for **pause** and **resume** functionalities. You can invalidate only **query function keys**.

If you are trying to invalidate the data after mutation, invalidate the key of query function where you fetch the users

Comment: you are only invalidating the `user-search` mutation cache. But there can be multiple mutations with the same key. So, it just invalidate the `user-search` mutation.

Comment: you can try calling queryClient.invalidateQueries("user-search", {exact: false}) to invalidate the useUserSearch hook mutation.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the `mutate` function with the `undefined` value to invalidate the mutation cache. So, in your `onSuccess` callback, you can try calling `mutate(undefined)` to invalidate the `useUserSearch` hook mutation.

```
const handleCreateRoleConfirm = (data) => {
  createRoleMutate(data, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      mutate(undefined); // call the mutate function with undefined value to invalidate the mutation cache
      showAlert({
        message: "The record has been created successfully",
        variant: "success",
      });
      setIsAddDialogOpen(false);
    },
  });
};
```

another way of doing this is to use `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` method with the `exact` flag set to `false` to invalidate all mutations with the same key. So, in your `onSuccess` callback, you can try calling `queryClient.invalidateQueries("user-search", {exact: false})` to invalidate the `useUserSearch` hook mutation.

```
const handleCreateRoleConfirm = (data) => {
  createRoleMutate(data, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      queryClient.invalidateQueries("user-search", {exact: false}); // invalidate all mutations with the same key
      showAlert({
        message: "The record has been created successfully",
        variant: "success",
      });
      setIsAddDialogOpen(false);
    },
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can only invalidate queries, not mutations. Mutations are there to fire off data to the backend and update state there. You can't "invalidate" that because its not a resource / query.
2. the `queryKey` you pass to `queryClient.invalidateQueries` needs to be an array. So given that you have a `query` with the `queryKey: ["user-search", data]`, you can target it with `queryClient.invalidateQueries(['user-search]')` instead of `queryClient.invalidateQueries('user-search')`